# multimodal circular model

Tags: st.statistics, stochastic-processes, pr.probability

Hi, can someone provide me with a list of probability models that is akin to Von Mises but consists multiple (potentially infinite) modes that takes into account attractors in the entire 2-D spatial domain?

Answer (score 2):

A mixture of Von Mises distributions?